# Optionally use Flash 10.2 cursors, while still being compatible with Flash 10.0?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, backwards-compatibility, mouse-cursor

I have a Flash application that requires Flash version 10.0 to run. I want to add native mouse cursors, which were introduced in Flash 10.2, but I don't want to require all my users to upgrade, and I don't want to have to compile two separate versions of my app.

Is there any way at runtime I can detect if the cursors are available, and then use them?

It seems like if you only compile for Flash 10.0, it marks the SWF version header "10", and you have no access to the new APIs. And if you compile for Flash 10.2, it marks the version header "11", and you have access to the new APIs, but can't run in the old Flash player any more (I get crazy errors while it's loading the Flex framework like:

```
VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of play2 in org.osmf.net.dynamicstreaming.DynamicNetStream.

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable _379fa43169660c76f131cadc0adfbfe8f347bd31d3ceec26a9cb2a56f0dda1f9_flash_display_Sprite is not defined.
```

Comment: As far as I know, Flash Player 10.2 is still in beta.

Comment: This isn't possible with a single SWF. You would need to do some version detection before loading and load in a correct version swf.

Comment: Such a pain, my SWF's are like 2MB total, and the difference is like 15 lines of code. I don't want to have to recompile the entire thing for a different version. They really should consider making Flash more forwards compatible.

Comment: Give the trick I outline below a shot.  I am not sure it if will work in your case, but I have done this in the past with success.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
var bitmapDatas:Vector.<BitmapData> = new <BitmapData>[new BitmapData(32,32,false, 0xFF0000)];

var MouseCursorDataClass:Class;
try {
    MouseCursorDataClass = getDefinitionByName("flash.ui.MouseCursorData") as Class;
}catch(e) {}
if(MouseCursorDataClass) {
    var cursorData = new MouseCursorDataClass();
    cursorData.data = bitmapDatas;
    Mouse["registerCursor"]("test", cursorData);
    Mouse.cursor = "Xmas";
}else {
    var customCursor=new Bitmap(bitmapDatas[0]);
    addChild(customCursor);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveCursor);
}

function moveCursor(e) {
    customCursor.x=mouseX;
    customCursor.y=mouseY;
}
```

And in fact the MouseCursorData object gets created and is valid in 10.2, but for some reason the browser crashes when trying to call Mouse.registerCursor(). I'm publishing for 10.0 though, so probably if you publish for 10.2 the whole thing works properly on both 10 and 10.2.

Comment: How can I publish for 10.2 using Flash Builder? (or if you know how to do it via the Flex SDK / mxmlc). I need to compile with the Flex 4.1 framework.

Comment: I think you need to download a special SDK (Hero?)... but if you need to compile with 4.1, I would try with MPD's solution ;)

Comment: If you compile with the newer SDK (Hero), it requires you to use Flash 10.2, and it wont run in 10.0 at all.

Comment: Are you sure about that? this SWF works perfectly in 10.2 and 10.1 (without the custom cursors in 10.1). Flash is usually very compatible with different versions of the same major release.

Comment: By "this SWF" I meant this one: http://corlan.org/downloads/examples/custom-cursors/CustomCursors.swf from this post: http://corlan.org/2010/12/02/working-with-native-custom-cursors-in-flash/

Comment: @Cay But how to compile? I don't want to have to port all my code to use the alpha Flex 4.5 framework. Is there a way to use the new compiler with the older framework? It always seems like the framework and compiler versions are tied together.

Comment: In order to do that, you have to replace the playerglobal.swc dependency.Replace the playerglobal.swc from your project by the one given with the Flex SDK Hero lastest release (4.5.0.18623). You can find the 10.2 playerglobal.swc in [FLEX SDK]/frameworks/libs/player/10.2

Comment: @Cay: I don't know about "this swf" running well on both 10.1 and 10.2 - I get a bunch of errors: `VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.ui::MouseCursorData could not be found. ArgumentError: Error #2008: Parameter cursor must be one of the accepted values`

Comment: It runs fine, but with errors in the debugger. That's what my code was for: take care of those errors through "try...catch" and "if" sentences, so you can seamlessly use one method or the other depending on which player you're running.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Mouse["supportsNativeCursor"]) 
{
  // do stuff with MouseCursorData...
}
```

Notes:

- This is equivalent to calling the property `Mouse.supportsNativeCursor`, but since `supportsNativeCursor` isn't supported either prior to 10.2 you need to check the property like this
- Some devices may not support cursors even if they have 10.2 (Android tablets don't have cursors) -- so be aware of that too!
- You may want to set this to a boolean because evaluating it probably gives a performance hit

Thanks to this video for this information. Skip to about 7:40 in the timeline :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtc3DYSuahI&feature=player_embedded#at=464

It's the video to accompany this article : http://everythingfla.com/quickies/native-mouse

Basically the solution is as follows:

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a definitive answer on this, but here are some thoughts.

Have you tried building your base application for 10.0 in one SWF, putting the 10.2 code in another SWF that is compiled for 10.2, then doing a version detect and loading the 10.2 SWF if the Flash player is capable of the features in the sub-swf?

I am not sure if this would work, though.  In the FP6, FP7, FP8 days, the root SWF controlled what features were really available, no matter what Flash player you were running in.  For example, if the root was for FP6, a subswf for FP7, and running in Flash Player 8, you would still be (mostly) limited to FP6 functionality.  Some FP7 features would work, but not all.  It has been several years since I have had to do this, so I don't know how this works with the AS3 engine.