# Flash custom cursor change direction when move mouse left/right

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm relatively new to Flash CS6, and I'm trying to make a custom cursor in a MS Paint clone I'm making. I want the cursor to turn right when I move the mouse to the right and vice versa.

My actionscript looks like this:

```
Mouse.hide()
mcGeit.stop()

var x_k:Array = Array();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, flyttMus);

function flyttMus(evt:MouseEvent)
{
    mcGeit.x = mouseX;
    mcGeit.y = mouseY;

    var i:int
    for(i = 0; i<100; i++)
    {
        x_k[i] = int(mouseX);

        if (x_k[i] < x_k[i-10])
        {
            mcGeit.gotoAndStop(1);
        }
        else if (x_k[i] > x_k[i-10])
        {
            mcGeit.gotoAndStop(2);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see what the error is, and when I start the file, everything flashes rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want best  responsiveness from the mouse cursor and avoid many problems (like double cursor/no cursor at all, having to handle out of screen/back to screen ..), you should use additional methods of `Mouse` class which allows you to customize the mouse cursor at the OS level.
It will require a bit more work though, since it's bitmap based

1. If your cursor is vector based : generate BitmapData's by drawing your cursors to a BitmapData of the right size using `mcGeit.getBounds()` and `bitmapData.draw(mcGeit,...)`
2. Create MouseCursorData Objects from BitmapData's and register them with `Mouse.registerCursor(...);`
   You should do it only once per cursor, as long as you dont' unregister the cursors.
3. at runtime, instead of `mcGeit.gotoAndStop(...);` call `Mouse.cursor = ...;` with a registered cursor name
4. At any time, `Mouse.cursor = "auto";` will restore the default cursor.

You can easily find tutos or resources about using native cursors

Keep in mind that it's not supported on very old platform (Flash Player < 10.2, AIR < 1.5) or mobile/tablets so if you relly need to support these cases, there is an example of how to detect the mouse cursor capability : [Optionally use Flash 10.2 cursors, while still being compatible with Flash 10.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610528/optionally-use-flash-10-2-cursors-while-still-being-compatible-with-flash-10-0)

Comment: This is by far the best way to do this (so much less overhead than using a MouseMove event).  I would recommend you improve your answer with a full working code example though.   Though the actual  answer to the question (it flashing) is the missing `new` keyword on the array instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly var x_k:Array = Array(); must be var x_k:Array = **new** Array();

```
Mouse.hide()
mcGeit.stop()

var temp:Number = 0;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, flyttMus);

function flyttMus(evt:MouseEvent) {
    mcGeit.x = mouseX;

    if(mouseX < temp){
        mcGeit.gotoAndStop(1);
    }else{
        mcGeit.gotoAndStop(2);
    }

    mcGeit.x = mouseX;
    mcGeit.y = mouseY;

    temp = mouseX;
}
```

I edit your code like this.